# OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error for Google Maps after 2500 requests

Tags: javascript, dojo, google-geocoder

Our application works perfectly in morning, may be till quota gets over but after that it never works on the day. We are facing below error.

As we are using Premium service, and registered client for Maps Version 3, everything looks fine. Delaying or timeout should not work as it seems its going in some loop.

Here is the code:

```
_resolveInitialLocation: function () {
                     var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + this._currentLatitude + "," + this._currentLongitude;


            if ( this._customerAddress ) {

                url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + this._customerAddress;
            }

            return xhr(url, {
                headers: { "X-Requested-With": null },
                handleAs: "json"
            }).then( lang.hitch(this, function ( place ) {
                // this._search( place.results[0] );
                this._place = place.results[0];

                if ( dom.byId("pac-input") ) {
                    dom.byId("pac-input").value = this._place.formatted_address;
                }

                this._currentLatitude = this._place.geometry.location.lat;
                this._currentLongitude = this._place.geometry.location.lng;
            }));
        },

        _initGoogleMaps: function ( /* Boolean */ preSearch ) {
            // summary
            //      this function will initialize google maps api
            // tags
            //      branch locator, google maps, maps

            if ( this._place ) {
                this._currentLatitude = typeof this._place.geometry.location.lat === "function" ? this._place.geometry.location.lat() : this._place.geometry.location.lat;
                this._currentLongitude = typeof this._place.geometry.location.lng === "function" ? this._place.geometry.location.lng() : this._place.geometry.location.lng;
            }

            var initialLocation = new 

google.maps.LatLng(this._currentLatitude, this._currentLongitude);
               .
..
..
                };
```

Please see the below error we are facing. We are using Dojo java script lib.

there is  a http request get error from the googleapis.com:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.280297,114.159514 
{
"error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_", 
"results" : [],
"status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a registered client for Maps Version 3 with a Premium account, most probably the URL was missing the parameter for the "API KEY".

> If you're using the API under the Google Maps APIs Premium Plan you
>   have two authentication options: Use an API key set up in the Google
>   Maps APIs Premium Plan project created for you when you purchased the
>   Premium Plan, or Use your client ID instead of an API key. [Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Comment: Thanks GibboK, this is the URL we are hitting..https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=gme-abcd&sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry,places&callback=initGoogleMaps    In URL, I have only changed company name with abcd. Pls help if naything wrong with it.

Comment: @SandipMante thanks for your message, if you think my answer was helpful, please do not forget to upvote or accept it using the icon arrow up or tick on its left side. Thanks and happy coding!